# No operations allowed after connection closed in play framework

Tags: java, mysql, scala, jdbc, playframework

the code works fine but i am noticing that sometimes it is giving error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

i am using a simple query and always it comes here(till now).

```
def result(id: String,mark:String) = {
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  val result = SQL("SELECT mark  FROM `subject` WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> id).apply().head
  if (result[String]("mark").equals(mark)) {
    Map("result" -> true)
  } else {
    Map("result" -> false)
  }
 }
}
```

i will provide more information if needed, because i also not seems any error in this code.

did i have to do something with this?

**application.conf**

```
contexts {
 simple-db-lookups {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 10.0
    }
  }
  expensive-db-lookups {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-max = 4
    }
  }
  db-write-operations {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 2.0
    }
  }
  expensive-cpu-operations {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-max = 2
    }
  }
}
```

I am using scala 2.10 with play framework 2.2

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/1243551

Comment: This sounds like Play 2.2.1 or 2.2.2. Probably time to upgrade.

Comment: @LimbSoup is `2.3.3` is stable version or i choose another?

Comment: @Salem why this error only comes with this query ? not with others query of my project

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti I don't know but it is weird  for you to get that only in that query... Have you checked if you dont get any error before that? BoneCP also has a bug that makes some exceptions get covered by others (ex getting a closed connection after trying to set null to a non null db field, without any reference to that)...